# Silverstripe 3: How to load a custom layout in a page template using a controller?

Tags: templates, layout, controller, silverstripe

Good morning,
Here's the scenario: I have a custom module and would like to load a layout for a particular controller action, but can't seem to figure out how. See example below:

[Directory layout]
  --root
   ---|themes
   -----|CustomTheme
   -------|templates
   ----------Page.ss
   ---|MyModule
   -----|templates
   -------|Layout
   ----------CustomLayout.ss
   -----|code
   -------|controller
   ----------MyController.php

*Note: The routing works fine, so I'll leave that out. See below snippet for MyController.php, Page.ss and CustomLayout.ss*

```
class MyController extends Page_Controller{
     ///> ... snippet ...
     public function someMethod(SS_HTTPRequest $request){
         if($request){
             $id = $request->param('ID');
             $dObj = MyDataObject::get()->byID($id);
             $title = $dObj->getTitle();
             $data = array( 'ObjTitle' => $title );

             //debug statement; It shows up, so I know the method is working!
             echo 'someMethod called!';  

             return $this->customise($data)->renderWith(array('CustomLayout', 'Page'));            
         }//if

         return $this->render();

     }//someMethod
}//class MyController

///>Page.ss snippet
...
<body>
   <!-- 
       I placed the text 'Layout:' to ensure that
       this template is being called, and it is! 
   -->
   Layout: $Layout
</body>
</html>

///>CustomLayout.ss snippet
<h2> Object Title: $ObjTitle </h2>
```

Now, I know $ObjTitle is working, because I've used a '$this->render($data);' statement before and called it from the Page.ss and it worked. I just can't seem to get the CustomLayout to load using the controller.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there is something very strange with SilverStripe that I don't understand.
I've been clearing caches doing complete rebuild's etc. (/dev/build?flush=1) before posting this question and nothing worked.

So, I've decided to try ?debug_request=1. Nothing shows up.
After going through the documentation, I saw isDev=1, to turn on development mode. 
So, I did that along with debug request like this: 
[url]?isDev=1&debug_request=1. I got a warning with 'strtotime' complaining about 'date.timezone' in php. So, I fixed it in my php.ini file and restarted apache server.

Upon restart, when I revisited my controller, everything is working as it should. So, there is nothing wrong with the code. It was something else, that I don't understand.

My gratitude towards anyone who was researching this issue.
If anyone has an explanation on this, please post it.
Thanks.

Comment: PHP 5.3+ requires that the date timezone be set. Setting it in the php.ini file is the proper way to do it, though you can set it for individual directories through htaccess: `php_value    date.timezone    America/New_York`